# How to transfer a block from one site to another?

Tags: 7, blocks, features

I've built a block on my local site and now want to transfer it to a remote site.

I thought this was done via Features, so downloaded the feature files and placed them on my remote server. On the remote site I accessed Features, checked the box of the updated Feature I placed up there and hit save.

I've cleared the cache and theme registry but the new block does not appear on the remote site.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Bean](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module. Here is a quote about its project page:

> Think of a Bean as a method to provide new types (compared to node this would be a content type) which then provides an add content interface to create as many blocks as you require (see screenshot below). The bean content can then be placed around the site just like any other block.

This module also works great in combination with the [UUID](https://drupal.org/project/uuid) and [UUID Features Integration](https://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) modules. And after you become familiar with the Bean module, you might find other cases in your site where you also want to use this module (which somehow compensates the fact that you need to add another module).

The video tutorial [Drupal Bean module tutorial - using Bean Admin UI](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu1YNy-BNG8) provides a great introduction to really understand the power of this module, and the kind of things you can do with it (by only using site building techniques, no custom coding involved). It also shows how the Bean module transforms Drupal blocks into fieldable entities.

This module only started as of D7 (because of the "entities" of course that were only introduced in D7), and already has over 22K reported installs. Those who don't use it yet should definitely start looking at it in preparation of some day upgrading to D8. Because this is what is currently shown on its project page (I added the bold markup here):

> **This module has been included with Drupal 8 core**. Refer to this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603894) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Block Export Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_export_import) module, It will help you to import block to remote site.

> This module allows users to export all system specific blocks (are
>   those blocks which are created using Drupal interface add block
>   functionality) and then import it into another Drupal installation, or
>   on the same site.
>
> No additional configuration is required to export/Import block(s).
>   Also this module does not create any table in the database. Therefore
>   it will not effect the application performance.